# running hello world program from developer.android.com

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to run the hello world program which is present on developer.android.com.I am using eclipse 3.4.1 version.

But when i run the program it doesn't give me any errors, but it doesnt display hello world either.
All it displays is the emulated device which i can get by running the android sdk also.

Answer (score 0):

Check your run configurations. Your Hello World application should at least appear in the emulated devices menu.

You dont need to close the dalvik every time you've run your application by the way. It takes a long time to load so just open it once then leave it open and run your application from eclipse.

Comment: when the output is displayed , does it stay on the screen or does it display and complete due to some time out ?

Comment: the hello world program stays on screen till you back out of the activity

Answer (score 0):

I dont know still what was wrong. 
But now it is working fine. Was a problem with the android sdk.